# Remove ".bash_aliases" with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, debian, wget, rm

In my .bashrc I'm using .sh script for easily configuring newly installed Debian. But while trying to

```
rm -f ~/.bash_aliases
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../.bash_aliases

rm -f ~/.bashrc
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../.bashrc
```

it's just omitting those line?
File is with permission `chmod +x ./script.sh` and run by `sudo ./script.sh`
What could possibly be wrong?

(In final code there is full link, files are being downloaded as `.bashrc.1` and `.bash_aliases.1`)

Comment: There's no conclusive evidence here that the lines *aren't* being run. Run `bash -x yourscript` to have the script log each command it runs as it runs it.

Comment: ...that said, if you want to override those files, I'd use neither `rm` *nor* `wget`. Use `curl --fail -o ~/.bash_aliases https://...whatever.../.bash_aliases`; curl's behavior is generally more predictable and script-friendly than wget's.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `sudo` unless you have a good reason.

When you run `sudo ./script.sh` it runs as root, so `~` refers to root's home directory `/root` instead of your user's home directory.

Just run `./script.sh` instead, so that it runs as you and modifies your own home directory.